# One question on a nowhere-dense set exercise

Tags: real-analysis

In a metric space X, consider a subset E. If for each open set O of X, O∩E is not dense in O, then E is nowhere dense.

Could anyone shed some light on the proof of this?

Comment: The body of your question should be self-contained. Please move the information in the title to the body of the question too.

Comment: @Wore is the body not self-contained as it stands now?

Comment: I think you are only including the definition of $E$ being nowhere dense. If not, then what is your definition of nowhere dense?

Comment: Let $U = \operatorname{int}(\overline{E})$. [An assumption that $O$ be nonempty is missing in the statement of the criterion.]

Comment: @DanielFischer The statement is for ALL possible open set O of X...

Comment: But fact of the matter is, $\varnothing \cap E$ is always dense in $\varnothing$, whatever $E$ is. And $\varnothing$ is open in $X$. Okay, the assertion as stated is also true, but it is vacuously true, the antecedent is always false if we don't exclude $\varnothing$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Am I missing something? What you said doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I think you meant to say "for each ***NONEMPTY*** open set $O$ of $X,$ $O\cap E$ is not dense in $O.$" If so, the problem is trivial, because "for each nonempty open set $O,$ $O\cap E$ is not dense in $O$" is the ***DEFINITION*** of "$E$ is nowhere dense." Well, maybe you are using some other definition of "nowhere dense." In that case, it might be helpful to tell us what it is?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. I don't know what, though. The antecedent "If for each open set $O$ of $X$, $O \cap E$ is not dense in $O$" is always false. For letting $O = \varnothing$, we have an open set with $O\cap E$ dense in $O$.

Comment: @bof Another widely used definition is "$E$ is nowhere dense if $\operatorname{int}(\overline{E}) = \varnothing$".

Comment: @DanielFischer And another one is "$E$ is nowhere dense if, for every nonempty open set $U,$ there is a nonempty open set $V\subseteq U$ such that $V\cap E=\emptyset.$"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your definition of nowhere dense is:

> **Definition:** A set $E$ is nowhere dense if the closure of $E$ has empty interior.

Then, we show the following:

> **Proposition:** *$E$ is nowhere dense if and only if for every non-empty open set $O$, $O\cap E$ is not dense in $O$.*

First, notice that if $E$ is not nowhere dense, then $O=int(\overline{E})$ is a non-empty open set and $O\cap E$ is dense in $O$: if $U\subseteq O$ is a non-empty open set, then $U\subseteq int(\overline{E})$ then there is $x\in U\cap \overline{E}$, which by the definition of closures implies that $U\cap E\neq \emptyset$.

Conversely, suppose that there is an non-empty open set $O$ such that $O\cap E$ is dense in $O$. Then $O\subseteq \overline{O\cap E}\subseteq \overline{E}$, and so $int(\overline{E})$ contains $O$. In particular, $int(\overline{E})$ is non-empty.

Comment: You showed that $U \cap E$ is not empty. Then what is the contradiction ?

Comment: The idea was to show that $O\cap E$ is dense in O. For that, you take an open non-empty subset $U$ of $O$ and try to show that $U$ intersects $O\cap E$. For that, it is enough to show that $U$ intersects $E$.

Comment: So you are trying to prove the contrapositive? Why does the fact that U intersects O∩E prove that O∩E  is dense in O? Dont you need to prove $O  \subset \overline{O\cap E}$ ?

Comment: To show that $A$ is dense subset of $B$ you have to show that for every non-empty subset $U$ of $B$, $A$ intersects $U$. In the proof I am putting $A=O\cap E$ and $B=O$. Notice finally that $O\cap E\supseteq U\cap E\neq \emptyset$, which finishes that part of the proof.

Comment: If $O\subset \overline{O\cap E}$, would that suffice for E to be dense in O?

Comment: Yes. Think about how would you prove that $O\subseteq \overline{O\cap E}$.